# C# - Replace newline by semicolon

Tags: c#, regex

With C#, I'm trying now to use Regular Expressions to replace newline (\n) in a text file by semicolon (;), but just if there is any content in that line;

If the text file is:

```
This is the program

Hello World
```

Then my return would be

```
This is the program;

Hello World;
```

I'm trying to use

```
my_str = Regex.Replace(val, "\n", ";");
```

But it affects also the lines without content.

Comment: thats becasue the lines without content also contain \n

Comment: Technically you want to replace it with `;\n` otherwise your return will be all on one line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [capturing 1+ characters followed by a newline](http://regex101.com/r/eK4eL4)?

```
(.+)[\r\n]?
\1;\n
```

[C#](http://ideone.com/pT82Sz):

```
my_str = Regex.Replace(val, "(.+)[\r\n]?", "$1;\n");
```

Comment: \1 gives me Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: @MarceloCamargo try `$1` not `\1`?

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work.

```
my_str = Regex.Replace(val, "(?<prev>.+)\\n", "${prev};\\n");
```

Comment: use \r\n if the text contains that